# Merging two folders with the same or different names

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shell-script

How can I merge two folders with the same or different names with subdirectories, using shell script or terminal. Also, if there is a file with the same name, then it should skip.

Comment: What operating system are you on? Is there anything you've already tried?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu. I want to merge using shell script or through terminal.

Answer (score 2):

To merge "dir2" into "dir1," I would expect the following to do what you want:

```
cp -nr dir2/* dir1/
```

The -r switch means copy recursively, and the -n switch means don't overwrite existing files (i.e., skip files with the same name).